# How can I speed up spawned prefabs on specific score?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have some prefabs which spawn randomly from my spawner and they have this script attached to them:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Enemy: MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 10.0f;
        private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private Vector2 screenBounds;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = this.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(-speed, 0);
    }
}
```

How can I increase the speed of the clones when, for example `Scorescript.score==10`?

Comment: See: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/128499/unity2d-increase-spawn-object-movement-when-player-collects-every-10-points/128504 This is for 2D but the logic applies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about simply checking it and apply that other velocity?

```
void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    // e.g. makes this object twice as fast if score is >= 10
    rb.velocity = new Vector2(-speed * (Scorescript.score >= 10 ? 2 : 1), 0);
}
```

---

If you want to be able to do this also afterwards you can either simply do it also in `FixedUpdate` and constantly check the score

```
private void FixedUpdate ()
{
    rb.velocity = new Vector2(-speed * (Scorescript.score >= 10 ? 2 : 1), 0);
}
```

or more efficiently you could use an observer pattern like e.g.

```
public static class Scorescript
{
    public static event Action<int> OnScoreChanged;

    private static int _score;
    public static int score
    {
        get { return _score; }
        set
        {
            _score = value;
            OnScoreChanged?.Invoke();
        }
    }
}
```

And then subscribe to the event in order to update the velocity everytime the score changes

```
public class Enemy: MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 10.0f;
    // You could reference this already in the Inspector
    [SerializeField] private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private Vector2 screenBounds;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if(!rb) rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

        Scorescript.OnScoreChanged -= HandleScoreChange;
        Scorescript.OnScoreChanged += HandleScoreChange;
    }

    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        Scorescript.OnScoreChanged -= HandleScoreChange;
    }

    private void HandleScoreChange(int score)
    {
        if(score != 10) return;

        // assuming the direction mgiht have changed meanwhile
        rb.velocity = rb.velocity * 2;
    }
}
```